# Export SharePoint 2007 InfoPath forms to PDF

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

We are currently in the process of migrating away from SharePoint 2007 and are looking for a way to migrate a large list of InfoPath forms that have been filled out either to PDF or to our new SharePoint. Any way to do this?

We're currently moving to SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint.

InfoPath Converter sees http://blog.muhimbi.com/2015/07/introducing-new-high-fidelity-infopath.html.

You can specify which views to convert / conversion specific views http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/21272887-how-can-i-specify-which-infopath-view-s-to-convert.

Convert InfoPath Forms including all attachments. http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/21275838-how-does-the-pdf-converter-deal-with-infopath-attachments